# Calculating how many decks of given size can be perfectly shuffled $k$ times and return to their original ordering.

Tags: group-theory, factoring, card-games, project-euler

This question originates from [Riffle Shuffles, Problem 622 on projecteuler.net](https://projecteuler.net/problem=622)

I´m just trying to wrap my head around something I just found.
I understand how to use the equation but not why it works.

So what i worked out so far is that the position of the $j$th card after a perfect shuffle is:
$2j \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 2n-1)$ where $2n$ is the size of the deck.

I also got how to calculate the sum of all deck sizes that satisfy a particular minimum shuffles.

In line with the problem proposed on projecteuler, here's an example determining the sum of all deck sizes that can be returned to their original ordering using 8 shuffles:

In this case the sum will be 412

You can calculate this by:

1. Get all divisors of $2^8 - 1$
2. Remove all divisors that are also divisors of $2^i - 1$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 7$.
3. Add all the remaining divisors together with the number(how many there are left) of all divisors

The question for me is: Why does this work? Or more specific, why can we just sum together the divisors that aren't also divisors of the same function with all real numbers greater than 0 but less then 8 to get the number of deck sizes that satisfy $k = 8$ shuffles?

**EDIT:**
Dumb question, we´re talking about the SUM of the solutions... Next time I´ll read the question twice but maybe this post is useful to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result is taken from [*The Book of Numbers. John H. Conway, Richard Guy.*](https://books.google.no/books/about/The_Book_of_Numbers.html?id=0--3rcO7dMYC&redir_esc=y) pp. 163-165, 1996.

If you have a deck of $2n$ cards, and you preform an [*out-shuffle*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Out-Shuffle.html). After the first shuffle, the card in the $j$th position in the deck is moved to the $2j \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2n - 1)$th position, and $k$ consecutive shuffles moves the $j$th card to the $2^kj \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2n - 1)$th position in the deck.

It follows that if the number of shuffles $k$ is a number such that $2^k \equiv 1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2n - 1)$ you would get the deck back in its original order. In your case $k= 8,$ so the problem becomes finding all deck sizes $2n$ such that $2^8 \equiv 1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2n - 1)$.

Consider the following python code:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 9):
print([2*n for n in range(1, 256) if 2**i % (2*n - 1) == 1])

Output:
[]
[4]
[8]
[4, 6, 16]
[32]
[4, 8, 10, 22, 64]
[128]
[4, 6, 16, 18, 52, 86, 256]
```

The output shows all decks of given size that can be put in their original ordering by $1$ to $8$ shuffles respectively. I didn't understand your calculation, but I suspect you are removing duplicates in the last list? That is, removing the decks of given size that can be shuffled into their original ordering by 2 and 4 shuffles, as 2 and 4 are divisors of 8.

**Edit:**

Here is a purely mathematical proof. The equation $2^8 \equiv 1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2n - 1)$ is equivalent to $2^8 - 1\equiv 0 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2n - 1)$, meaning $2n - 1$ divides $2^8 - 1$. This gives you a concrete way of checking whether a deck of size $2n$ can return to its original order after 8 shuffles.

In general this can be extended to say a deck of size $2n$ can be shuffled $k$ and return to its original order if $2n - 1$ is a divisor of $2^k - 1$. Note, this only tells you that it is possible to shuffle it $k$ times and have it return to its original order, but not that $k$ is the smallest such number. This explains how your calculation is valid, you are simply removing duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get that part, but why could I, in this case just calculate: (256-1)+(86-1)+(52-1)+(17-1)+4 to get the number of deck sizes that satisfy minimum shuffles = 8? In this case the answer would be 412, which is correct.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Assuming you meant the sum (256 - 1)+(86 - 1)+(52 - 1)+(18 - 1) + 4, this is just the same as the sum you get in my answer. Your answer is more clever, as you set $2^8 - 1 \equiv 0 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2n - 1)$, which just means that $2n - 1$ divides $2^8$. The act of removing the duplicates like I did, is the same as finding the divisors of $2^i - 1$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 7$ and removing those.

You have to add in the number of divisors at the end, because you've subtracted one from each divisor.